# convert a pointer of array in Java

Tags: java, c, binary, arrays

I'm trying to convert a program in c to Java.
I don't know c programming, I'd like to understand a bit btw.

well I've got those functions in C:

```
static int memcmp( Byte *a, Byte *b, int len) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        if (a[i] != b[i]) 
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

static int rfind(Byte *data, int pos, int leng) {
    int i;
    for (i = pos - leng; i > -1; i--) 
        if (memcmp(data+i, data+pos, leng)) 
            return i;
    return pos;
}
```

that I can't workout.
It seems the function memcmp compare two blocks of memory.
When i get the size of data:

```
printf("size %d \n", sizeof(data));
```

I got 8 for the result while the orignal size can 32 or 40 (any good documentation about pointers is welcome).

Anyone who could help me to translate this bit to Java will have all my gratitude (and even more).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't have pointers, so you can't translate the code directly.  In C, you can treat pointers as arrays, whereas in Java you will need to use indexes into the same array.  This is more or less as direct a translation as I can come up with:

```
public int rfind(byte[] data, int pos, int len) {
    for (int i = pos - len; i > -1; i--) {
        if (memcmp(data, i, pos, len)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

public boolean memcmp(byte[] data, int idx1, int idx2, int len) {
    for (int i = idx1; i <= len; i++) {
        if (data[i] != data[idx2 + i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

As ayush points out, if the `data` array is an ASCII string, you can get the same result in a much simple way by using library calls.

```
String str = new String(data); // convert data byte array to String
String sub = str.substring(pos, len); // substring pointed to by pos
int rfindResult = str.lastIndexOf(sub);
```

Comment: I think for memcmp it would be more useful to give two arrays instead of only one.

Comment: It would be more useful in general, but for rfind to use that, you would need to create two new arrays and copy the desired range from the original array to the new ones.  That would work but would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

to compare string and byte array's you can use `Arrays.equals()`.

as far as rfind goes you can use lastIndexOf() http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/the-equivanent-of-rfind-in-java-603139.html

Comment: This assumes, of course, that the Byte arrays are actually strings.  That seems like a reasonable assumption, but if that were the case I would expect the original code to use char* not Byte*.